# Getting PermissionError while downloading files to local machine from SFTP server using pysftp

Tags: python, sftp, pysftp

I'm unable to copy files from SFTP server. I'm getting the permission error.

I have tried changing the mode in `os.mkdirs()` function.

```py
sftp = pysftp.Connection(host = myhostname, username= myusername,  password= mypassword, port=22, cnopts=mycn`enter code here`opts)
os.makedirs('S:\\work\\Automation\\ML\\Procressed data\\FY20\\FW'+fweek+'\\output', exist_ok=True)

localpath = 'S:\\work\\Automation\\ML\\Procressed data\\FY20\\'+fweek+'\\output' 
englishpath ='dell.ccaprocessrepository/output_ts_2020'+fweek+'_English_EU.txt'
chinapath = 'repository/output_ts_2020'+fweek+'_CHT.txt'
japanpath = 'repository/output_ts_2020'+fweek+'_Japan.txt'
koreapath = 'repository/output_ts_2020'+fweek+'_Korea.txt'

sftp.get(remotepath= englishpath, localpath= localpath)
sftp.get(remotepath= chinapath, localpath= localpath)
sftp.get(remotepath= japanpath, localpath= localpath)
sftp.get(remotepath= koreapath, localpath= localpath)
```

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'S:\\work\\Automation\\ML\\Procressed data\\FY20\\29\\output'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `localpath` argument of pysftp [`Connection.get` method](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pysftp.html#pysftp.Connection.get) is a path to a *file*, where the downloaded contents should be stored to.

The `output` in your `localpath` is a *folder*, not a *file*.

You need to append a filename to the path.

```
englishlocalpath = localpath + '\\output_ts_2020'+fweek+'_English_EU.txt'
sftp.get(remotepath=englishpath, localpath=englishlocalpath)
```

---

Alternatively, change the local working directory to `localpath` and you can omit the `localpath` argument. pysftp will download the file to the working directory, keeping the original name (taken from the `remotepath` argument):

```
os.chdir(localpath)

sftp.get(remotepath=englishpath)
sftp.get(remotepath=chinapath)
sftp.get(remotepath=japanpath)
sftp.get(remotepath=koreapath)
```